# can karate read files from outside the classpath with a relative path instead of absolute path

Tags: karate

I'm trying to read a properties file for karate-config.js. It works when i provide the absolute path from my local but when i provide a relative path. it doesn't work. Any way around this? Thanks !

var config = karate.read("file:/repo/tests/utils/al_dev.json"); -- This doesn't work
var config = karate.read("file:~/repo/tests/utils/al_dev.json"); -- This doesn't work
var config = karate.read("file:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/repo/tests/utils/al_dev.json"); -- This works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working. I had to update the path to reflect the project structure and it worked.

```
    var config = karate.read("file:../../utils/al_dev.json");
Project structure:
project1 -> 
    tests -> 
      Utils -> 
      Services ->
         client 1 ->
         client 2 ->
```

Answer (score 1):

I took advantage of answer wrote by Peter Thomas and it worked for me, I could read a json body from a file somewhere else in the project, not needed to be in the same folder as features. This is a sample of code I used:

```
Scenario: POST with json file reading from anywhere.
    Given path "/api/apitesting/v1/transactions"
    And def projectPath = karate.properties['user.home']
    And def filePath = projectPath + "/IdeaProjects/01 Courses TM/karate/src/test/resources/data/TestBodyAnywhere.json"
    And def requestBody = read('file:' + filePath)
    And request requestBody
    When method post
    Then status 201
```

As you can see, I used **user.home** instead of **user.dir**, (which use to be recommended but this points directly to the same folder where you are calling it instead of pointing to outside that folder). **User.home** points directly to your root user, so it would be something like this *C:/Users/MyUser*. Then, from there you can start indicating the relative path in a new variable to your file. Finally, remember to use 'File:' keyword inside the read method and concatenate it with your path variable.

Hope it helps. ;)

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Karate (Java) can't resolve these special OS paths. I guess you know that this is not recommended, best practice is all test resources be kept under the project root. Anyway, here is a workaround:

```
* def home = java.lang.System.getProperty('user.home')
* def temp = read('file:' + home + '/repo/tests/utils/al_dev.json')
```